# Puppet graphite configuration

Tags: apache, module, puppet, graphite

Good Day,

I am trying to automate my graphite install on ubuntu 14.04. The installation runs smooth and everything installs without error. But once the install is done I get a **403 Forbidden** error. Manually installed Graphite and it works. I would appreciate some help or guidance to understand why it is not working using puppet.

Puppet Version: 3.4.3-1 using this module for graphite: dwerder-graphite

This is my puppet configuration:

```
  class { 'graphite':

  gr_max_updates_per_second => 100,
  gr_timezone               => 'Europe/Berlin',
  secret_key                => 'CHANGE_IT!',
  gr_web_servername         => '127.0.0.1',
  gr_web_cors_allow_from_all => 'true',
  gr_apache_port             => '80',
  gr_storage_schemas        => [
    {
      name       => 'carbon',
      pattern    => '^carbon\.',
      retentions => '1m:90d'
    },
    {
      name       => 'special_server',
      pattern    => '^longtermserver_',
      retentions => '10s:7d,1m:365d,10m:5y'
    },
    {
      name       => 'default',
      pattern    => '.*',
      retentions => '60:43200,900:350400'
    }
  ],
  gr_django_db_engine       => 'django.db.backends.mysql',
  gr_django_db_name         => 'graphite',
  gr_django_db_user         => 'graphite',
  gr_django_db_password     => 'password',
  gr_django_db_host         => '127.0.0.1',
  gr_django_db_port         => '3306',
  gr_memcache_hosts         => ['127.0.0.1:11211']
}
```

Please note that I am testing this module and I am running it from a localhost/virtual machine.

Comment: This is more of a ServerFault question, I feel. Cannot be solved without having a look at pertinent error log contents.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at file permissions and ownership: is user running the server able to access the webdir.

Comment: I have since just re-written the module that was supplied from the vendor. now it works. the issue was in the template config used